# can you branch in xslt depending on output format?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm creating an xlst script and was wondering if it is possible to branch some code depending on the output format?

On top of my xlst file I have this:

```
<xsl:output 
 version="4.0" 
 method="html" 
 indent="no" 
 encoding="UTF-8" 
 use-character-maps="spaces"/>
```

So I suppose there is something out there to inquire some sort of global to do this:

```
<xsl:if test='global_output is html'>
      do this
</xsl:if>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but... Why? If you wrote the code you should know what's the serialization method you'd chosen. The only scenario where I can think this is relevant is in case you import/include/reuse the same content template for stylesheets with different output method. But even in that case you know from where you are invoking it and you could pass this information as parameter. Although this wouldn't be a real case because there is no reason for using the same content template for different serialization methods anyway.

Comment: @Alejandro: the reason is I'm using Altova StyleVision and I created an xslt template to generate the pdf output. StyleVision is able to generate xslt for both my html and pdf versions. But the template I import for the pdf is only good for pdf. So by this little hack I don't have to keep 2 separate altova projects.

Comment: If the template you are importing is "only good for pdf" don't import it for the html version...

Comment: it's good for both. And Altova suggestion is to branch for output type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create variants of a stylesheet for use in different situations, don't put if/then/else code inside the template rules to test the condition at run-time. That way you end up with spaghetti. Create two stylesheet modules to-html.xsl and to-xml.xsl, and have both import a module common.xsl that contains the shared code. The common.xsl module can call back to the importing module when it needs to invoke functionality that varies between the two cases. One of the differences between the two cases is of course the xsl:output declaration itself.

Comment: Well you are absolutely right. But I'm using a software to generate the xslts' files for html and pdf, so I need a single file to generate both. To be more thorough, I should create a 2nd file to create a proper xslt file with no hack.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.0 one can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output version="4.0"
    method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="document('')/*/xsl:output/@method = 'html'">
            Output method is HTML
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="document('')/*/xsl:output/@method = 'xml'">
            Output method is XML
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

May be there is a classier way to do it in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: the `xsl:output` instruction actually used migth not be the one in the stylesheet of the current expression.

Comment: @Alejandro. It's a really limited hack for a really weird requirement.

Comment: Thanks, xsl correct in my case. I used <xsl:if test="$SV_OutputFormat = 'PDF'">. Your code helped me understand.

Comment: This is a horrible hack. If the code needs to do this, then the design of the application is wrong, and should be rethought from the ground up.